# How to draw a mask (circle) over an Android webview?

Tags: android

I have three weeks into Android development (newbie). Is it possible to draw a mask over a webview so that the webview looks like its a circle? My webview is showing google map (dragable). I want that map in the app to look like its a circle, instead of a rectangle that is filling the entire Layout.

Comment: follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914555/masked-bitmap-on-canvas-with-transparent-activity

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes.  But your webview will be unaware of the mask, so you might run into problems with the mask covering parts of the UI.  I don't know about the Google Maps web API, but the Android API lets you set padding to move the controls and Google logo away from the edges.

You can create a custom `View` in which `onDraw(Canvas)` instructs some other `View` to draw into a bitmap, then applies a mask to the bitmap and draws it on the output `Canvas`.  To make your webview appear circular, you'd place the custom view on top of the webview, and configure the custom view to use the view *below* the webview for drawing.  This would create the appearance of a hole through the webview.

Shameless plug: I published a [MaskView](https://github.com/kjkrum/MaskView) that does exactly this.